# Selector with filter or search option in SAPUI5

Tags: select, search, filter, combobox, sapui5

I am making a form and one part of it is to put the telephone number. I want to divide this input in two, on the one hand a selector with the prefixes of all the countries (I get the information from a json) and on the other hand a normal input with a restriction of numbers. The problem is that as there are many prefixes I would like to see if there is a way to filter the numbers with a select because with a comboBox I can filter the problem is that it gets out of the form and the sizes are not good, however with the select everything goes correctly. I have tried these three ways but, the first one I don't think is the best, then the second one I can't look for the result and the third one it overshoots the width of the cell. Any ideas for the select?

```
<VBox>
    <Label class="label" text="{i18n>Phone}" required="true"/>
    <HBox>
        <SearchField id="prefix" placeholder="Prefijo" enableSuggestions="true" search=".onSearch" suggest=".onSuggest" suggestionItems="{ path: 'country>/Dato' }">
            <SuggestionItem text="{country>prefix}" key="{country>code}"/>
        </SearchField>
     <!--<Select id="prefix" items="{ path: 'country>/Dato' }">
            <core:ListItem key="{country>code}" text="{country>prefix}"/>
         </Select>-->
     <!--<ComboBox id="prefix" class="input" width="30%" required="true" items="{ path: 'country>/Dato' }">
            <core:ListItem key="{country>code}" text="{country>prefix}"/>
         </ComboBox>-->
                                            
         <Input id="phone" placeholder="{i18n>Phone}"  value="" class="input phone" type="Tel" required="true" maxLength="10" liveChange="handleLiveChange"></Input>
    </HBox>
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L6 M6 S12"/>
    </layoutData>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example and explain in detail the current behavior and the expected behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You could use sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm to encapsulate your UI elements.
Then add 2 elements such as sap.m.Select and sap.m.MaskInput inside your form.

Here an example : https://jsbin.com/xotokavamo/2

Feel free to edit it to fit your use case.

```
<script>
        
      var oForm = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({
        layout: "ResponsiveGridLayout",
        editable: true
      }); 
      
      var oLabel = new sap.m.Label({text: "Phone"});
      var oInput = new sap.m.Input({placeholder: "Enter phone number"});
      var oMaskInput = new sap.m.MaskInput({placeholderSymbol: "_", placeholder: "Enter a 10 digit number"})
      var oSelect = new sap.m.Select({items: [
        new sap.ui.core.Item({text:"+33"}),
        new sap.ui.core.Item({text:"+81"}),
      ]});
      var oHBox = new sap.m.HBox({
        items: [oSelect, oMaskInput]
      })
      
      oForm.addContent(oLabel);
      oForm.addContent(oHBox);
    
      
      oForm.placeAt("content");
        
    </script>
```